# How do I bind to XmlDataProvider whos source has a default namespace (xmlns) set?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, xaml, xpath

I have XML similar to the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo name="FooBar" xmlns="http://mydomain/myapp/ver/myschema.xsd">
    <bars v="test">
        <bar bat="one"/>
        <bar bat="two"/>
        <bar bat="three"/>
    </bars>
</foo>
```

How do I map this in WPF, it works if I don't set the default namespace, however when I have `xmlns` set my binding does not match anything. I have tried the following declarations however I'm having trouble figuring out how to map the combo box as shown below.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- works if xmlns is not set -->
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="mySource1"
                     XPath="/foo">
    <!-- also tried -->
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="mySource2"
                     XPath="//*[local-name()='foo']">
    <!-- also tried -->
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="mySource3"
                     XPath="/foo">
        <XmlDataProvider.XmlNamespaceManager>
            <XmlNamespaceMappingCollection>
                <XmlNamespaceMapping
                    Uri="http://mydomain/myapp/ver/myschema.xsd"
                    Prefix=""/>
            </XmlNamespaceMappingCollection>
        </XmlDataProvider.XmlNamespaceManager>
    </XmlDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource mySource1}">
    <Label Content="{Binding XPath=@name}"/>
    <Label DataContext="{Binding XPath=bars}"
           Content="{Binding XPath=@v}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I'm assigning the `XmlDataProvider.Source` property through the following code.

```
XmlDataProvider xdp = FindResource("mySource1") as XmlDataProvider;
// ... setup dialog and confirm resource.
using (Stream s = dlg.OpenFile()) {
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(s);
    xdp.Document = doc;
}
```

Any help solving this would be very much appreciated, thanks.

**UPDATE**

From Andrews suggestion I've come up with the following:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="mySource"
                     XPath="/fb:foo">
        <XmlDataProvider.XmlNamespaceManager>
            <XmlNamespaceMappingCollection>
                <XmlNamespaceMapping
                    Uri="http://mydomain/myapp/ver/myschema.xsd"
                    Prefix="fb"/>
            </XmlNamespaceMappingCollection>
        </XmlDataProvider.XmlNamespaceManager>
    </XmlDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource mySource}">
    <Label Content="{Binding XPath=@name}"/>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=fb:bars/fb:bar}"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@bat}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I've found the problem stems from the fact that my real world problem is binding to a combobox's `SelectedItem` which doesn't seem to be working with the namespace, opened follow-on question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909416/having-trouble-getting-parent-child-combobox-to-bind-against-xml-datasource-prob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this ? I am not too familiar with xml namespaces.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- also tried -->
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="mySource3"
                     XPath="/cs:foo">
        <XmlDataProvider.XmlNamespaceManager>
            <XmlNamespaceMappingCollection>
                <XmlNamespaceMapping
                    Uri="http://mydomain/myapp/ver/myschema.xsd"
                    Prefix="cs"/>
            </XmlNamespaceMappingCollection>
        </XmlDataProvider.XmlNamespaceManager>
    </XmlDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel DataContext="{StaticResource mySource1}">
    <Label Content="{Binding XPath=@name}"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding XPath=cs:bat}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, this pointed me in the right direction, however I'm still having a problem mapping nested elements, I've updated my problem as shown above. I've also updated the XML to reflect the problem. The other side is I really don't want to have to specify a prefix everywhere in my XAML and would prefer not doing this.

Comment: I tried out your edited code and it seems to work without binding errors. I can see a label "fooBar" and a combobox with "one,two,three".  I am not sure if there is a way to remove the prefix. I have never seen it being removed in xaml before.

Comment: As you found, it does work, I'm not sure what's wrong in my real world problem however. Something funky is happening with it as it behaves as expected without namespaces. I must be missing a prfix somewhere and not noticing. Thanks for your help Andrew.

Comment: Hi Andrew, found the root cause of my problem that I've been having, it appears that binding to a combo-box's `SelectedItem` is causing trouble. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909416/having-trouble-getting-parent-child-combobox-to-bind-against-xml-datasource-prob